# Sort nested dictionary by values

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to sort a dictionary with another dictionary inside. This is how my dict looks like:

`{'POS2': {'stegano': 0, 'sum': 200, 'misc': 100, 'web': 0, 'ppc': 0, 'crypto': 0, 'admin': 0, 'vuln': 0, 'forensics': 0, 'hardware': 0, 'reverse': 0, 'recon': 100}, ...}`

I want to sort it by `'sum'` key that is stored in nested dict. I have tried different solutions like here [Sort nested dictionary by value, and remainder by another value, in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110665/sort-nested-dictionary-by-value-and-remainder-by-another-value-in-python) and here [sorting a nested dictionary with lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719654/sorting-a-nested-dictionary-with-lists-in-python) but they all work fine on python 2.x but doesn't work on python 3.x. Could you give me advice how to implement this kind of sort ?

Comment: You linked to the same question twice. The accepted answer there *works just fine* for Python 3. What error do you see?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Pieters It's also works only on python 2.x. On 3.3.4 it says "TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing"

Comment: The **other** post has the same answer as I posted below though, so this **is** a dupe of [Sort nested dictionary by value, and remainder by another value, in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4110665)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply return the desired sort key from each item

```
sorted(inputdict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['sum'])
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I meant to sort the items, not the values.