# Sort nested dictionary by inner values

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I sort this nested dictionary by the inner values. The keys will change so cannot sort by keys. The keys are integers and the values are floats.

```
NestedDict = {'1': {2: 0.3, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 3: 0.75},
              '2': {5: 0.3, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 1: 0.75},
              '3': {15: 0.3, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 70: 0.75}}
```

This is the result I need. The values are sorted from greatest to least regardless of the keys.

```
# NestedDict = {'1': {3: 0.75, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 2: 0.3},
#               '2': {1: 0.75, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 5: 0.3},
#               '3': {70: 0.75, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 15: 0.3}}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607278/sort-nested-dictionary-by-values

Comment: Saw that post already. My structure is a nested nested dict, not just a nested dict.

Comment: and as you can see, the keys dont have any static names.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to get an "ordered dictionary"? The order in which keys appear in a dict is dependent on the insertion order and I'm not sure it can be changed. You might want to use `OrderedDict`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @ayhan, Im on 3.7.

Comment: @gst, yeah OrderedDict was one of the first I tried.

Comment: Sorting dictionaries isn't really a thing. What are you actually trying to do with the results of this operation?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6 -- I'd interpret "``dict``s in all Python implementations must preserve insertion order" to mean you cannot change the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to rebuild the dictionaries in an ordered way. From Python 3.7 onward the order in which you add items to a dictionary is preserved.

```
NestedDict = {
    outer_key: {
        inner_key: inner_value for inner_key, inner_value in
        sorted(inner_dict.items(), key=lambda d: -d[1])
    }
    for outer_key, inner_dict in NestedDict.items()
}
```

Now `NestedDict` is

```
{'1': {3: 0.75, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 2: 0.3},
 '2': {1: 0.75, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 5: 0.3},
 '3': {70: 0.75, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 15: 0.3}}
```

Outer level is the same but for inner level we are iterating over a sorted version of the inner dictionary (sorted by their values, given by `d[1]` where the minus sign indicates a decreasing order).

Comment: Thank you. But I am afraid I don't know how to implment the above as I just tried. Would you mind writing it mentioned assingment in full?

Comment: @HelloWorld123 Oh I just meant `NestedDict = {outer_key: ... ` I've updated the answer. Let me know if it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to dictionary comprehensions. Not necessarily better, different. This is predicated on Python 3.6 or greater, which maintains insertion order, else one must use an `OrderedDict`. Dictionary comprehensions do *not* give you that option.

```
NestedDict = {'1': {2: 0.3, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 3: 0.75},
              '2': {5: 0.3, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 1: 0.75},
              '3': {15: 0.3, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 70: 0.75}}

keys = [k for k in NestedDict.keys()]
dict_values = [v for v in NestedDict.values()]
dict_values = [dict(sorted(x.items(), key=lambda kv: -kv[1])) for x in dict_values] # or OrderedDict

NestedDict = dict(zip(keys, dict_values)) # or OrderedDict
print(NestedDict)
```

Prints:

```
{'1': {3: 0.75, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 2: 0.3}, '2': {1: 0.75, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 5: 0.3}, '3': {70: 0.75, 7: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 15: 0.3}}
```