# Sorting dictionary of dictionary of tuples - Solution works for list for doesn't work for tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, sorting, ordereddictionary

I am trying to use `OrderedDict` in Python where I am ordering the dictionary data using `lambda`. Somehow I am not able write this correctly. With reference to this post

[sorting a nested dictionary with lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719654/sorting-a-nested-dictionary-with-lists-in-python)

I tried to order my dictionary using two keys 
1. First group (Info, Code, Process etc)
2. As second tuple value of inner dictionary (7, 2, 45, 18, 19 etc). However, not getting what I want. Here is my input -

```
   a = {'Info': {3: ('info1', 7), 4: ('info4', 2)},
         'Process': {1: ('info2', 45), 8: ('info8', 18), 10: ('info11', 19)},
         'Code': {23: ('info3', 45), 27: ('info21', 34)}}

print sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1].values()[0][1], x[0]))
```

Ultimately, I want to get this information in an `OrderedDict` and iterate over it in a particular order.

Can anyone help?

Thanks for the response folks!
Just adding the expected output. See, first it's ordered by the main key (Code, Info, Process) and then the inner dictionary is ordered by second element in the value tuple (34, 45), (2,7), (18, 19, 45)

```
a = {'Code': {27: ('info21', 34), 23: ('info3', 45)},
     'Info': {4: ('info4', 2), 3: ('info1', 7)},
     'Process': {8: ('info8', 18), 10: ('info11', 19), 1: ('info2', 45)},
    }
```

I am OK if we skip the first key ordering i.e. only the inner dictionary is ordered by second element in the value tuple (34, 45), (2,7), (18, 19, 45). So the expected answer in this case would be:

```
a = {'Info': {4: ('info4', 2), 3: ('info1', 7)},
     'Process': {8: ('info8', 18), 10: ('info11', 19), 1: ('info2', 45)},
     'Code': {27: ('info21', 34), 23: ('info3', 45)},
    }
```

I hope this explains my problem.
Again thanks for responding so quick.

Comment: can't you simply do `oD = OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1].values()[0][1], x[0])))` ?

Comment: Can you please show us the expected output?

Comment: doing `x[1].values()[0]` isn't really a great idea.  You don't know which value you're looking at since the values' order isn't well defined.

Comment: thx njzk2, thefourtheye, mgillson for comments. I have added more specifics about the expected answer